# How to view php file in plaintext?

Tags: php, directory-traversal

I have downloaded php file of a website through path traversal technique, but when I opened the file with notepad and notepad++ I only get encrypted text. Is there any working way to view that file in plain text and understand what is there in that file, I am asking for a education purpose only. help me out

I get following text in that notepad file,

```
ELF              Pi4   ´õ;     4    (      4   4€4€               4  44                    € €È½8 È½8           À8  @= @=Ä4 ìå          ð9 ð“=ð“=À  À           H  HHD   D         PåtdP½8 P==P==            Qåtd                          /lib/ld-linux.so.2           GNU                       GNU /eNœó¼5‘Ù•áwÿ:ªÝFÿl  …  j  º              =  ì
        Ã  ¬  r  ®  =          q  ë  œ  Ö  '      q  l  Æ  é  Ž  q      ‡  â    1
      €      v  Ï
      þ    Ò                  ï       N          Ö    L  À  ¨  ¤      €  D
  ¼          ð      
  b      3        t
      í      á          d      ’      þ   ³          Ä  ó  É    
  ò           >        Ý
    {      l  7          1  ¿      ±  &
      ¬      ä  Û    /                 b      ¤            ¢  n  !                  c      F              Ý   2  “            S          €  X      ¾  ¿  _  ±  ž  D  w  Ý      ²  õ        #  ˆ   y  Þ  ú  N
      2  ç                      
              g              O       
    Ÿ              B  c  º              0  n          ¥  ÷  ?  +              &        õ                j  Ã
    ø  Ê      L  g
  ˜  <  ¡  §      è      3  Š  Q  «  °  í  ª  ¦   º            *      W           È  ©  ´      Õ      ò  ¼              D      e  Ó
  —  6  ®  ×  ü  ~  W      i  @  £  ½  ì      ¼  ³          K  ø      @    É
  Û    F  Ï  õ
  ¬      ê      O  ü          ê  #      }      {  ü
    L  ?  Ù                  w   $            P  ü          _                ©
  ¶      «  â    ú  é  …      w  Ô          F          V  h  M
  z      ²  ê  ·  j      ?  Â  W   a   Ó  ’  Æ  ‚

      X
  ˆ  B  k  V  ~  £
  e    5  X  ¨  @  ¢
  _        v
  r  5  ú  ¸          G              D  L  ç  /          ´  H      –                     @      q      „              ×          Ä  Ð          ˜  ]  J    ñ  S  M         á  ô        M      ~            <    
  ²      Ï      í      #  ×      E      ×  ^      Î  4      À  Þ      »   ï          Y  Ä  †      z            f  b  a      }            V      5      Ã  y              #      á  p
       2   B  ü      þ  ¸      H  Ò      €  K  š  ï          ³  Ü  T  \                    ÷      Â  T  U      œ  °       ˜      Ê
  }  `  N      p    Ñ  á  x  %  r  ”  l                      î  L    ò  à      è      ,
  §  ý  í  ‚  T  ÿ
  w      Í  '     X  6  ë
  ;      '      ›  ã    ÿ
  J  ”    s      H   M            \                q    *
  5                    ?      «
  ë  –  6  –      œ  Ó   t  1   ô
  N          ï  ×      R  9  ¾  –  
  ˜  ³                              Ÿ      i                  æ
          ’
  ®      µ              (      ‰  R  ·    X          D  ´     t          Ô
      ›        n  é  ¹      À      m               -              K            
  •     ª

  ·  Ý      –  Ý      à        k    B  Ù  x
  É
      Ü  (    O  ;        ×  å      Ÿ  ú
  û        f      ¶  Ú  ‚  ß      o  x
  |          Ó  3  Ê  ®
      '  ‡  D
  ù          
          {  j
  5  Œ  ©  ;  *  Ñ      S  ¥      À      ~  0  (    0  ­  t
      u  Ç  9
    O  5        ½   ½      €      ø   €  ;  ­     .  ë  ß      U  `            F          Z  ¶          (  b    i       ­  4      â  J
  9  K
      ç                     Z  ~
  å  e  Ò  l                  2  Ö  m  å      Ë           «      v  !      \    '  ™              Ð          B        
          L            Ì  7  A   
  s
  ­  Ü     )
      ®  B  â  ø  
      E            ‡
          æ
  Ý
              2      0  œ        #          ó  &  º      P  —          ÷      ì      p        …
  é           ^       d       ]      ?  è      ¤  Þ  „  …  ¸   Û      4  ½      (  =    Z      Û
     !      #  H  â  
  Ã  Ë
        ö              ½                  Æ  g          w
  u                        k            r      Z      S  Ý        Á  c      *  ¶
  a      ê

  ’
  b  <                ®  C    f                  ß  /     w  i          „          –      à    i  Å  õ      
  Ú          ¦
          þ
      j  ±        œ      ±  Ã  ©      7

  ²      ý  ¨  @  ¥   …   8  @  "      u  ;  †  v      .  7              õ        ä  m  Ç     ’       v  Ð        ä  ¨  

  ß  1            r      Ñ  Ÿ  F  Õ    ¢  O  »  C  ƒ          q  Ÿ    ë      I        ø  Õ      N              Š        H     v  ¤  !             (  ù        ©     »      9  Q      ,  ›      œ  ¶  f        ¢  1  a     2   ®  ?      Q            f
  _  K      æ              ¯
      û      \  †  À    ð  E  ²  ˜        Ž  ¶  ù   Õ
      þ  
  ‡  ž    X
  ¥  «  ¯  °  Ü  ,
  :      `
  é
  -   G  ¸    O
  ±          I  n        ›          n  ü    e  q  1      “      a  Ì          ?        ¶  »      
  n
  N  _  R      =          3                  Z  ˆ      Ñ  A  Ü          X         ¥  Ð  ·    °  ¸         û    h  :
  f  c  Ù  .  
     Á  Î          &      ’  Å  ø  y              [        Y  w  ?  d        ƒ  Þ      •  >
  8             ¤      ¡      k    ó    R  i      Œ
      ¥             Õ  2
      ‹      Ê  Ü  Ö  Œ  Ý  <  n  —    Z  
    „  ý  Å      
  Å
  ‰  ˆ          Ú  ž  N    b  /  °       K      O              ‘      Î  æ          ¨  ¿    A  k  â  ò          s      Ë      ¯  »  M          l      …  ¼  Þ      I
          ;      `  œ             Ž          %
      l    .            ü                  R           ‘  o
  Ò

  ¬  -            C  Ñ
      Ð      õ      ¨             ƒ           …  u
  (
    ‚  Û  -                      ¯  V          C  Œ              Ä                      

      ¦  •     *
  (
  p  ¸  %   ’          ì  \     ¨  Ø    ¿              *  )  ­  W  U  ó
      ã              Q  â  
              }  ß  È                  Ó          ì          ¦  è  n  ¢      ô  6     e      ¬         !  ¦  „
  8  z                    O  ã      Ü    V    –  «
  9  D  u      z          :  d  ¤  Ð  w  r        $  ¹
  ¹  ‹      ø  V  J   å  t  Á     ‚      Y  y
  [          <  °  j      ¼  û  K  î  ï  q  Ô   •     0   ”
    ç  –          l
  ç  R  m         Ó  H        {  :  '    Ü  “  ”  Ÿ  ?
  "  è                        §          y          >  L
            ¦  k  (   Ø  ¨      s            F  G  I  K  •  A  Ü  Þ
  =      ·              M              º
  í  7        ®              Y  .  ¨
    )  ˆ  /                      ú  ¢  -  á  .  Z
      Ë  ,    É  ç
  ý          ö                  Æ      ¬  ®     ¬
  ¤        .  z  á  p  û      Í      
  ¾          ·  Î      É  —  `  u  ‰  °  ž          <
      ¯          l      Ž  ¿  ;  =  ‡  
  G    ´  k  ]  |  ;  Â      5                Ê  ³  %  é          W  ÿ   ó          ê            °      ¥  v    4    ´            k  g                0     ›  é  6  W    <      
      §        *      ‘
  z  €  m  P  Ý   «  G      Ä  š
  ›
  ä  <     A
        `          Ñ      v  ˜          ç      “          Ê  ¡
  Q
  !
  h      i
  f      “  :  Ô  }
  š  Ù  ,      û  ÷                 g
          í  ó   2  ‹  G      p   ‹    n               Î  ü  Ô      U  ¤  ·  8  ½      Œ      o
  ¥                  «   Y  /  ‘  x           y   î      Ë  A      o          æ  a  Ù
  F  (  ™  ¼          Ÿ      ê  ý    ‰          ë  ©  ª                 
  û  ™      ¿  M      „   W  é   ý    Ž          Ë  V  e  }      „

  ¯          ›      þ  z  !      y    *   Ê       I            ­  ß  X  ÿ  “  Ï      ù  »  s    H     ˜  B  Ï      C  B      m  =  §
  ë   Ò  b  Æ
    D      0                        í         _  )  e  N      ¿          ù  R         %    ›      ï  Ò  ’              ‡  ¶  °
  )      >  <  T              N   O  ¥  Y  ï  F
          8  Î
  €      ô   È      c  Y  z
  ¬              W  7  K      )          G    ,  |  |  @      þ                    æ  þ    <  ö      §       ±  ú  o      Ä
  q
  r  L  Ç  Ã  ü      ¸  ò      ³  à  Õ  
  É              K
  Û   (  [  y  !      ð    Ì  W  ›    ,        +      õ    H      ß  å  -      b  Ø        '    
  ×
      `  o                E   
  Ÿ  )  B      )  …    »    "
  ˜  ó
          |      ±  ñ  O      b             c         n  ^
  Ç      ”  >          O  +
     Ù  ì  Z      q  Ë              ù  û  º  J  O  q  a  
  U          G  x      l            R          ¯  C  »    
  ê  V  S  ð      h         ¸      |  Š  ˆ
  F          N  
          Y
  ×      "  '      Þ  R                 ‚     Ž  ‘
      ¤      $
                      _   ´
  ~                |  ç                €
  3            –
  æ       8  ©  ¨  $  ý  ¼  m      p
      ì  °      †            À      Ô  Ä  ‰  ¶      ·
  ‹  þ
      Ð  ß      %  Q
         %  Œ
      Š       w              ö      »   ž  ¦  þ        ó    §             š  ×
    9  <  Ú  m  P      F      ƒ      ˜  Þ  9  Â      
                       ÿ  â  .  ä  ~  º    Ö  ñ  ‰  Œ  ‘          ³
  Q  )
  Ñ  '
      ‘       ”      '    Ž   )  ¢  ¼         ç  î  Ã  æ           S  
  0
  a  ì                  ë          x  j  $  &  H        ÷             û
  ø      ~      
          4  ¯  ‘      ‚  á  Á
  r  =
  ÿ      y  @  ‰  Ç  R  Î
  Â      È  v
  '  ›      
    Ø
      ¯   î     Ã            ,              0  œ  6  "  %  M              =      ú  I
  •      p      V  g      u               Š  ^  À  e          Ð    µ  !  #  Ž  —  Q         4
  ‹   4
  =  ê  à
    [  +      Ä          I  ¾  K      J  .  c  Û  
    y  é                a
  Æ      ª  ¨      D           /      P      Ù  â  `  š        n  †  W      Q           X  k        ë  j  ¢      ‚   {    ô  3  þ    ì          Ž
  Ì  I      
          Ô  Ù      Ä         g      ñ  ä     ‹      ¨  Å            §  )       Æ  ç      ;
  :  ƒ  ö
  ­          ~  
      ]  _  ©
  c  Õ  f  m  o  u  ³      Ú        {  ª  ë  
  ç  ƒ  å  þ          }            ¿  Ù              7
    ¥          Ÿ  ;     Î     ò
  ú  9      ¯      ‚
  ö    –              `          ¹  Í  Y
  Í   >  ƒ      Õ                —      Å      &  ³      u      æ      D      4      ú    Z      w        s  º  2
                        –    m    »  g              Ù  ‘  1  ¬  È  Ó  —          ¥  5      ]  r  

  ª      ö
      q  –
      a  /  Û  "  $  Q  õ   æ  ß  ú         3  W  ç  Y  î  7  É       y
  è
  µ   Ô   _            ,      Ÿ      ì
  \  ø
  k  ƒ  h
      {  Ó  '            †      ô     f  ›
      !         ?  K         c
  ×      A  h   I  0  ô  ^  '      &  Å      Ð
  ó          
            è       Ç  ¡      æ  º   |
              ö  p  D                           å        
  a    ñ  Ì  |  ¹  Ù      Ö  V              ò                  T  "      ¦  â  d
        ·   (  Z      *  f  5
         ¸          ¯  x    ;          4  Á  á  Ö  ß  m      Þ    ´
      í
  Z  ¡        ¿      ”  É     ‡  Œ      /          é  £  z  ¡  ©  f    Ä  4   C      3        »    >  ¸      }
  ¥  £  g       ¶
              §  u        Å  ï          Ë          ö              ‰  t      ;          A          ‡  p  %  ‚          Ï  6  è  ð  „  n          ¡          h    B  4    F  1  
  ¼  ½  ¿  ã      6           '
  †  È      i
                  Ü  Þ          3         0  [  ˆ      ¶  œ
  f  #  -    á                      &  ñ            
  Œ        n
  Ä      ¿  ”      ¹  †   
  …        
  å
  Ã     ˆ  Ü  C  ü  ¹      p    »      -      ¡  ‹
  þ  È      ×              U  }  Ó  ‘              o  >      #  ÷  ¯  !
    ð  m      ù       c  [          Â  ‹
  A    2  +  M                r  ë    m  ;      .  ó  ñ          K          à  È
      L
  Y  Q  T  Û  …    ¡      œ  @          G               ö      T  Ø  º
      „          h      œ  Ð  …  ô          ’  Á  £  .
      e  ]   º  œ  ß  ¤
      á      ú  ã
  ì   š  L  ‘  ô  @  p  w  š                                L  J        /
          ¦  ˆ      9          å      ²          ç          
  “        :  >  d  9      ²      ,     ÿ         ½    V    ®  £          è
  Ê          O  ^          w  =   >  å      Ž  g  D      “
  ë        i  z               '  Œ  ÷  ¤      y      Ò  ð  ƒ
  n  µ
      |  ô  Ë  {      e              +        “      D      F   Q      t  Í      <
  9              Á    â  z  ê     Õ
  P
```

NOTE: I copied only few lines from that entire file

Comment: "path traversal technique" which is what exactly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't download a `.php` file, and it's not encrypted.

You downloaded an [ELF executable file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), as evidenced by the ELF signature in the first bytes.

Perhaps if you show the path you managed to download, we might be able to determine exactly which executable you managed to download from the server.

Comment: Thanks for your response sir, The path I downloaded this php file is 
"website.com/usr/local/php/"

Comment: @sincere.sundar That path ends in a slash (`/`) - is there a filename afterwards?  I'm guessing you downloaded the PHP binary, which is mostly useless.